# Error when migrating JDeveloper to 11.1.2.3.0

Tags: java, oracle, jdeveloper

I used to work on JDeveloper 11.1.1.1.0 and had a project all set up.

I installed a new PC (64-bit machine) and a new JDeveloper (11.1.2.3.0) and wanted to run my existing project on it. When porting the project to the new JDev i was asked if i wanted to migrate the existing files to the new JDev format and i clicked on 'Yes'.

Upon compilation, I got no code compilation errors. However, the compilation failed due to this error: "Error: An unreported error occurred in Appc. No errors were reported, but the tool returned a failure result code: 1. "

I turned on verbose mode, but couldn't get any additional messages that indicate what the problem might be. I've seen a series of threads where people discuss similar problems, but no-one ever mentioned if he/she resolved the issue.

Some information about my system:

```
JDeveloper version: 11.1.2.3
java.version: 1.6.0_45
java.vm.info: mixed mode
java.vm.name: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM
java.vm.version: 20.45-b01
```

Let me know if more information is needed and thanks in advance.

Comment: This is to whoever is still experiencing this problem. I ended up migrating to a lower version 11.1.1.7. The migration was successful and my project ran successfully. I haven't tried it yet but im pretty sure that the problem was that i was migrating from a pretty old version to a somewhat very recent version. If you migrate to some middle version as a first step, i think migrating to newer versions would work seamlessly.